# What is the definition of "needy" according to Islam?

Tags: sharia, definitions

As you know, there are plenty of Thawab (reward) in aiding poor people.
In fact, there are plenty of traditions concerning alms-giving to the needy people. As all of us know, a needy person is a person who his/her income is not sufficient for him/her to pass his/her life well, and perhaps we encounter many poor persons in streets who are begging people for money (as Sadaghah).

My question is that:

What is the precise definition of needy in accordance with Islam?
Actually who can be called as a actual needy in Islam? (That we can give him/her the alms?)

Comment: The one who needs something is needy, in any religion not only Islam, so if someone needs a spoon of salt, try to help him, because he is the needy.

Answer (score 2):

Scholars usually define a needy person, as someone who can only find a part of his daily needs (e.g. food, clothing etc.) and has no or little income to support him/herself and/or their families.

Borrowing money to pay for basic needs is usually a strong indicator that someone is needy. If you can speak Arabic, YouTube has many videos from top scholars on Zaka and the types who receive it. And I'm pretty sure it has English resources as well. Also, [IslamWeb](http://islamweb.net) is a trusted website with many resources and fatwas (English and Arabic) to aid you; you may also send in your questions to them. I highly recommend that you refer to these websites to avoid any mistakes or confusion.